# Jquery not working in plain JSP

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery. I have written a small code and running on Tomcat 6. Somehow it is not working. 
Please see below my code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/javascript/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/javascript/jquery/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script>
$("body").on("click", function(){
    alert("test");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me what is wrong with this code.

Comment: any error in browser console?

Comment: no errors in console.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){}); put your event function inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap it into an ready handler like so:

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("click", function(){
        alert("test");
    });
    // All other jQuery functions would go inside this same wrapper
});
```

Hope this helps!
More info here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/